# Use beautifulsoup4 in Alexa developer console

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup, alexa-skills-kit

I need beautifulsoup4 to scrape through a websites HTML and get information. I want to use that information in my Alexa-skill.

How do I import/use bs4 in my Alexa developer console?

I've already read how to make a deployment package (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html), but I don't understand how to download/zip bs4.

I am new to Python, AWS and Alexa developer console, so I am sorry if that question is very easy to answer.

Kind regards,
Dany

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find all you need here at this documentation url: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Hello, I stated that I already read this link but do not understand it.